# Internet only works for a minute or two then won't work anymore

Tags: networking, drivers

After a minute or so, the wifi stops working as in, it is still connected to the wifi but there is no data being transferred. This started happening when I upgraded the kernel to 4.17 (from 4.15) and it won't even register my usb adapter when i run 4.17 but will only work for a minute or so. If I log into windows on the same system with the same wifi adapter everything works good. I have confirmed that this is not a problem with my general wifi because it works when I boot into windows on the same machine, and it also works on my laptop which is also running Ubuntu. Before this happened, it has been working with no hiccups for 5 months since I switched over on this pc.

I followed these commands to install my driver back when:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
sudo cp -r rtl8812au  /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2
sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
```

lsusb

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 145f:01c1 Trust 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:5104 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

ifconfig

```
enp33s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 30:9c:23:03:94:d2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enx000f004aa319: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 2600:1700:16e0:6d90:1522:cd74:5f8a:6dc3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2600:1700:16e0:6d90:be9b:318:b16d:dfcf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::ae05:cd57:188b:30dd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0f:00:4a:a3:19  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10399  bytes 13031066 (13.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1816  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5708  bytes 760985 (760.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1011  bytes 93331 (93.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1011  bytes 93331 (93.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.                           
       physical id: 0                                                    
       bus info: pci@0000:21:00.0                                        
       logical name: enp33s0                                             
       version: 15                                                       
       serial: 30:9c:23:03:94:d2                                         
       size: 10Mbit/s                                                    
       capacity: 1Gbit/s                                                 
       width: 64 bits                                                    
       clock: 33MHz                                                      
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s                             
       resources: irq:35 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fe604000-fe604fff memory:fe600000-fe603fff
  *-network                                                              
       description: Wireless interface                                   
       physical id: 1                                                    
       bus info: usb@3:1                                                 
       logical name: enx000f004aa319                                     
       serial: 00:0f:00:4a:a3:19                                         
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless                                                                                                       
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8812au multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will give you some hints.

Comment: I ran the command and I've noticed it saying, "no ifupdown configuration found".

Comment: 4.17 is not a Ubuntu supported kernel, so you may not be getting security updates for it (unless you patch the kernel yourself or other non-Ubuntu patching set up). Security patches are backported to the 4.15 kernel for 18.04 LTS, or you can use the 4.18 kernel (with HWE enabled).

Answer (score 0):

- Ubuntu has the driver included in it’s repository these days. For
  Ubuntu you have to enable the universe package sources.

  **sudo apt-get update**

  **sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms**

Reboot

But even then it might not be perfect because the drivers are not open source and **up to date for the kernel up to 4.15** at this moment in time.

They can be downloaded from https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software

Eventually they will update the driver and the package manager will update the package so waiting might be an option but you need the package installed to do that.

- So the second option is to downgrade the kernel to 4.15 and you will
  be sure the WIFI will be working. (I would install the correct driver
  anyway.) [How to downgrade kernels](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/)

Comment: I ran "sudo apt-get update r8168-dkms and my computer said its already installed and at its newest version"

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, I really appreciate it. But I'm on 4.15 right now. I upgraded to 4.17 and it started with the problems and eventually just didnt recognize my usb adapter so i moved back to  4.15 but it only stays connected for a minute or so (this is the same behavior as 4.17 in the beginning before it got worse ).

Comment: Try  "sudo apt purge r8168-dkms"  followed by "sudo apt install r8168-dkms" followed by a reboot

Comment: it did not seem to change anything. another guy said to run `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` to help see the problem and i see the error `noifupdown configuration found.`